# Huffman tree node

Tags: java, tree, comparative-review, compression

I've implemented a Huffman tree for one of my academic coursework. For each of the nodes in the tree, there will be a left child, right child, and a parent. For each `Node` class, to add the children, I have the functions, `addLeftChild()` and `addRightChild()`. All is good.

However, I am a bit divided for the function that adds the parent to the node. I am unsure whether to use `addParent()` or `setParent()`.

My personal argument for using `addParent()` is that it is consistent with the naming of the other 'add*X*()' functions. What deters me is that using 'add' implies that there's another parent. For using `setParent()`, semantically it makes more sense for me that you would set another node to be a parent.

Here is my code:

```
package app.utils.ds;

public class HuffmanNode
{
    private HuffmanNode leftChild;
    private HuffmanNode rightChild;
    private HuffmanNode parent;
    private char letter;
    private int frequency;

    public HuffmanNode(char letter, int frequency)
    {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.frequency = frequency;
        this.leftChild = null;
        this.rightChild = null;
        this.parent = null;
    }

    public void setParent(HuffmanNode parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void addLeftChild(HuffmanNode child)
    {
        // I'm thinking of renaming this to setLeftChild()
        this.leftChild = child;
        this.frequency += this.leftChild.getFrequency();
    }

    public void addRightChild(HuffmanNode child)
    {
        // I'm thinking of renaming this to setRightChild()
        this.rightChild = child;
        this.frequency += this.rightChild.getFrequency();
    }

    public HuffmanNode getLeftChild()
    {
        return this.leftChild;
    }

    public HuffmanNode getRightChild()
    {
        return this.rightChild;
    }

    public char getLetter()
    {
        return this.letter;
    }

    public int getFrequency()
    {
        return this.frequency;
    }
}
```

What is your opinion on this? Also, how else can I improve the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node can have at most one left child, and at most one right child. If you call `addLeftChild()` twice, the second call would overwrite the result of the first. Therefore, I would prefer `setLeftChild()` over `addLeftChild()`.

The same naming advice goes for the parent node. However, I would **change `setParent()` to be private**. Users of this class should not be required to help you set the parent node pointers; the `HuffmanNode` class can do it automatically within `setLeftChild()` and `setRightChild()`. That would eliminate the possibility of letting the caller create an inconsistent data structure.

Is it important to allow child nodes to be removed? If so, `setLeftChild()` and `setRightChild()` should be prepared to handle a `null` argument.

In the constructor, you could eliminate the three `… = null` assignments. Those are implicit already.